# Nesting and group by variables in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a big data file that contains multiple records of data from different sources. I am trying to create multiple datasets from this file to pass onto a glm model in r. Some of the data is complete, and some is lacking.

This is the data example

```
df<- structure(list(Date_sno = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Cause = c("A", "A", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), age_group = c("old", "young", 
"old", "yound", "young", "old", "old", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), gender = c("M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Area = c("North", "South", 
"North", "South", "North", "South", "South", "North", "North", 
"North", "North", "North", "North", "North", "North", "North", 
"South", "South", "South", "South", "South", "South", "South", 
"South", "South"), Temp = c(14, 12, 50, 60, 12, 30, 35, 12, 45, 
30, 45, 60, 20, 12, 31, 32, 12, 45, 30, 45, 60, 20, 12, 31, 32
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Date_sno = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Cause = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), age_group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Temp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Now I am trying to create a dateset that contains a group by (Cause, age_group, gender) AND contains all the other data from that day/area that has no Cause.

Iv'e tried this but it eliminates all the non cause data

```
nested <- df %>% group_by (Cause, age_group, gender) %>% nest()
print(nested)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Cause, age_group, gender [7]
  Cause age_group gender data             
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <list>           
1 A     old       M      <tibble [4 x 3]> 
2 A     young     M      <tibble [2 x 3]> 
3 A     old       F      <tibble [2 x 3]> 
4 B     yound     F      <tibble [2 x 3]> 
5 A     young     F      <tibble [2 x 3]> 
6 B     old       M      <tibble [2 x 3]> 
7 NA    NA        NA     <tibble [11 x 3]>
nulls <- df %>% filter(is.na(Cause))
```

Now the main point is to insert into each df in data column, the rows that are in nulls, if the area matches, and if the date is not already listed in the df.

EDIT:

Thanks for the comment on the final format not being clear enough.
This is an example of one of the outputs, I need all of them nested in one Data frame..
This output represents the df for A,old,M. After the group by and nesting all of the NA lines were added to it. this should be done the same with the other dfs..

[image: Output Mock]

EDIT 2:
Iv'e edited the main explanation again. I hope it's better

Comment: It was edited.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make `NA` an explicit character value, so these can all be grouped together:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), "NA")) %>%
  group_by (Cause, age_group, gender) %>% 
  nest()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   Cause, age_group, gender [7]
#>   Cause age_group gender data             
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <list>           
#> 1 A     old       M      <tibble [2 x 3]> 
#> 2 A     young     M      <tibble [1 x 3]> 
#> 3 A     old       F      <tibble [1 x 3]> 
#> 4 B     yound     F      <tibble [1 x 3]> 
#> 5 A     young     F      <tibble [1 x 3]> 
#> 6 B     old       M      <tibble [1 x 3]> 
#> 7 NA    NA        NA     <tibble [18 x 3]>
```

Comment: Thanks. See my edits for more detailed information. This still leaves out all the nulls, which i want to add to each nested df

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the expected output is.  In `dplyr` 1.0.0, it is not dropping the `NA` only rows for groups

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by (Cause, age_group, gender) %>%
   nest
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Cause, age_group, gender [7]
#  Cause age_group gender data             
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <list>           
#1 A     old       M      <tibble [2 × 3]> 
#2 A     young     M      <tibble [1 × 3]> 
#3 A     old       F      <tibble [1 × 3]> 
#4 B     yound     F      <tibble [1 × 3]> 
#5 A     young     F      <tibble [1 × 3]> 
#6 B     old       M      <tibble [1 × 3]> 
#7 <NA>  <NA>      <NA>   <tibble [18 × 3]>
```

Comment: @Stat.Enthus I get the same output with the new data update

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please look at the output, as the rows that are NA for cause etc. should be added to each nested data frame, that is my real challenge..

Comment: @Stat.Enthus If we do a group by 'Cause', the `NA` will be a separate group. It is not clear about the format of your expected

Comment: Thanks. That's why I think an inner join or a self left join is needed, I tried to edit it again..

Comment: or an anti-join

Comment: @Stat.Enthus issue is that if I do a group by Date_sno, Area, and fill Cause, age_group, gender, there is confusion among which observation goes into that, i.e. `df %>% group_by(Date_sno, Area) %>% fill(Cause, age_group, gender)`

Comment: Iv'e edited the main explanation again. I hope it's better